# Django REST Framework, Serializers: Additional data?

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework, request

Good day,

I would like to ask, if there's a possibility to gain additional data inside my serializers?
These are my models...

**models.py**

```
class Chair(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, blank=False, unique=True)
    bookable = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    user_created = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    date_created = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)

class Booking(models.Model):
    chair = models.ForeignKey(Chair, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    day = models.DateField()
    user_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    user_created = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    date_created = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
```

and these my serializers...

**serializers.py**

```
class BookingSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Booking
        fields = '__all__'


class ChairSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Chair
        fields = '__all__'
```

When making a request inside js like this...

**views.py**

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def bookings_by_date(request, pk):
    bookings = Booking.objects.filter(day=pk)
    serializer = BookingSerializer(bookings, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

**script.js**

```
let url = '...here's my url for Booking...';

fetch(url)
.then((resp) => resp.json())
.then(function(data) {
    // do something here
});
```

...I would like to get not only the id of the Chair (models.Foreignkey), but also it's name. My first thought was doing something like this...

```
class ChairSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Chair
        fields = [
            ...
            'chair',
            'chair__name',
            ...
            ]
```

...but this doesn't seem to work! Does anyone know a solution for my problem? Thanks for all your help and have a great weekend!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use one of this two ways:

1-) Using  [SerializerMethodField](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield). You can add readonly fields with this way. You should add `get_<field_name>` method or give a method name that you want to run for this field with name keyword. You can look the document for more details.

```
class BookingSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    chair__name = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Booking
        fields = '__all__'

    def get_chair_name(self, obj):
        return obj.chair.name
```

2-) Using CharField with [source](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#source) attribute:
You can  define basically this field fill from where.

```
 class BookingSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    chair__name = serializers.CharField(source='chair__name')

    class Meta:
        model = Booking
        fields = '__all__'
```